# Show multi polygon using leaflet js (1.3.1) from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm trying to show multi polygon from the database. But it seems doesn't work at all.

before that, I tried to use data arrays then it successfully shows.

Here is the code when using array data

```
var latlang = [
        [[-6.909428, 106.937143], [-6.918034, 106.939761], [-6.919142, 106.929804], [-6.909513, 106.929976], [-6.909428, 106.937143]],
           [[-6.911218, 106.937357], [-6.918844, 106.94195], [-6.910877, 106.952593], [-6.911218, 106.937357]],
           [[-6.918673, 106.924955], [-6.9237, 106.928002], [-6.920036, 106.93135], [-6.91829, 106.930577], [-6.916074, 106.927659], [-6.918673, 106.924955]]
    ];
    var item = new L.polygon(latlang, {
        color: '#ff00c8',
    });

    // Adding multi polygon to map
    item.addTo(map);
```

Now, I'm confused if load the lat lng coordinate from the database. How to loop and replace latlang var.
I'm trying to `console.log(json_data);` and the result shows

Here's [a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNYfM.jpg)!

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use an IDE and beautify feature to have nice code.

if you copy and paste you latlang https://beautifier.io/ you will see it like this:

```
[
    [
        [-6.909428, 106.937143],
        [-6.918034, 106.939761],
        [-6.919142, 106.929804],
        [-6.909513, 106.929976],
        [-6.909428, 106.937143]
    ],
    [
        [-6.911218, 106.937357],
        [-6.918844, 106.94195],
        [-6.910877, 106.952593],
        [-6.911218, 106.937357]
    ],
    [
        [-6.918673, 106.924955],
        [-6.9237, 106.928002],
        [-6.920036, 106.93135],
        [-6.91829, 106.930577],
        [-6.916074, 106.927659],
        [-6.918673, 106.924955]
    ]
];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hmdshariati/cLy4gups/5/

that is three polylogon. your database data is a triangle like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/hmdshariati/cLy4gups/8/

be careful to use lat and lang in correct place.

Comment: So, how to solve my problem?
I don't understand what are you trying to say, because it's mutli polygon so it should be more than one polygon in map

Comment: you should push the array fetched from database to latalang array for multi purpos. latlan.push(...the latlang result of fetched data...)